# Making a Database table in SQL, weird error

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

This is the code for the Database.Its giving me an error that for every TABLE created something has already taken that name, one of the error messages is at the end of the post.

```
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE Team (
  Team_ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  Team_Name NVARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  Team_Manager VARCHAR(20),
  CONSTRAINT kkeyconst PRIMARY KEY(Team_ID)
 );

 COMMIT;

 insert into Team(TEAM_NAME, TEAM_MANAGER) VALUES ('Red Sox', 'Jon');
 insert into Team(TEAM_NAME, TEAM_MANAGER) VALUES('White Sox', 'Tony');

CREATE TABLE Driver (
  Driver_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Teams_ID INTEGER,
  Driver_age INTEGER,
  Driver_Name NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT DriverAge CHECK (Driver_age BETWEEN '19' AND '65'),
  CONSTRAINT driverpk PRIMARY KEY(Driver_ID),
  CONSTRAINT Teams_PK FOREIGN KEY (Teams_ID) REFERENCES Team(Team_ID)
  );

 COMMIT;

  insert into Driver(DRIVER_AGE,DRIVER_NAME) VALUES ('21', 'Jon');
  insert into Driver(DRIVER_AGE, DRIVER_NAME) VALUES ('20', 'Tony');

  CREATE TABLE Participation (
    TeamName_ID INTEGER,
    Driver_ID INTEGER,
    PointsEarned INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT TeamName_FK FOREIGN KEY (TeamName_ID) REFERENCES     Team(Team_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Driver_FK FOREIGN KEY(Driver_ID) REFERENCES Driver(Driver_ID)
   );

  COMMIT;
  insert into Participation(PARTICIPATION_POINTS_EARNED) VALUES (150);


CREATE TABLE Finish (
  Racer_ID INTEGER,
  Finish_Position INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Fishish_Result VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Racer_FK FOREIGN KEY (Racer_ID) REFERENCES Driver(Driver_id)
);

COMMIT;
  insert into Finish(Finish_POSITION, Finish_RESULT) VALUES ('1', 'Winner');
 insert into Finish(Finish_POSITION, Finish_RESULT) VALUES ('3', 'Third   Place');

CREATE TABLE RaceComponent (
  RC_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Driver1_ID INTEGER,
  RC_Type VARCHAR(25),
  CONSTRAINT Rcpk  PRIMARY KEY(RC_ID),
  CONSTRAINT Driver1_FK FOREIGN KEY (Driver1_ID) REFERENCES Driver(Driver_ID)
  );

 COMMIT;
  insert into RaceComponent(RC_TYPE) VALUES ('Hot Wheels');
  insert into RaceComponent(RC_TYPE) VALUES ('Tonka');



CREATE TABLE Race (
  Race_Id INTEGER,
  RC_ID INTEGER,
  Race_Title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Race_Location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Race_Date DATE,
  CONSTRAINT RACPEK PRIMARY KEY(RACE_ID),
  CONSTRAINT RC_FK FOREIGN KEY (RC_ID) REFERENCES RaceComponent(RC_ID)
  );

  COMMIT;
  insert into Race(RACE_TITLE, RACE_LOCATION, RACE_DATE) VALUES ('Tonys    race',   'Moncton', DATE '2016-04-25');
  insert into Race(RACE_TITLE, RACE_LOCATION, RACE_DATE) VALUES ('Mikes Racing',     'San-Francisco', DATE '2015-04-25');
```

ERROR:

```
Commit complete.


Error starting at line : 3 in command -
CREATE TABLE Team (
  Team_ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  Team_Name NVARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  Team_Manager VARCHAR(20),
  CONSTRAINT kkeyconst PRIMARY KEY(Team_ID)
)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Commit complete.
```

I thought it might be because I am calling the Foreign keys the same name as their primary key value, but im not 100% sure what is causing it.

Comment: You may have another table with a primary key called `kkeyconst`. I'm not familiar with the Oracle syntax for checking to see if that name already exists elsewhere.

Comment: Caution: `Team_Manager` is defined as `VARCHAR(20)`, should be  `VARCHAR2(20)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table was created during an earlier run of your script, you will get that error.  It is always good to check to see if your table already exists before trying to create it.  Here is a good snippet of code from StackOverflow for checking to see if the table already exists or not.

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
BEGIN
    --Do Stuff
END
```

Comment: Oh my i completely forgot about that. Thank you.